# what’s the names of the card game that uses 8 decks of cards?

Tags: identify-this-game

This card game was played by 3 women at a Sr Center and it took 3 hours. Eight decks of cards used to play this game.

Comment: You're going to have to edit in some more details about how the game played if you want more than us just shooting in the dark.

Comment: yes please describe the game further, what interactions they made? did they use any other tokens, dices, etc.?

Answer (score 7):

Could it be [Hand and Foot](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/handfoot.html), a variant of Canasta? It uses multiple decks and has each player trying to build 7-of-a-kinds while emptying their two hands (the second being called the foot, hence the name). If they aren't playing cut-throat and instead just going for high scores, this game can theoretically go until every single card sans the 3s are melded.

Comment: OMG...you are correct! I’ve been racking my brain for days and finally stumbled on this website. Thanks so much, I can sleep tonight.

Comment: Ha, turns out I didn't even need any more clues. No problem.